# Android in app billing currency code is always USD

Tags: android, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am trying to use the getSkuDetails() method to get the currency code: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference. However the privacy_currency_code is always USD. I tried to things:

(1) VPN to another country from my PC and create a google account, then add that account to test device
(2) VPN the test phone to another country

But in both cases the privacy_currency_code in getSkuDetails is still USD, so why that happens? In the play store console the in-app product is marked with USD. Not sure if that's the cause. If that's the cause why it doesn't automatically convert?

Answer (score 3):

In Play Console have you mark the SKU available for non-US countries? If not, then it defaults to US price.

Also, Google Play allows you to change the country but be aware there is a long cool down of 1 year
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en

Comment: yes I did. Looks like after VPN you need to resign in to your google account on your  phone to see the price_currency_code change

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a vpn, select another country in your phone and create a google account. (important to create a new account, otherwise google "knows" where you are from)
2. Go to settings, apps, google play, clear cache.
3. Open your app.
   After changing your vpn to another country, clear play store cache. dont need to create one account per country.